# How should I refactor complicated If else block in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view, view-helpers

I have following code in my view:

```
# panel.html.erb
<% if content.content_type == "image" && content.content_image_url =~ URI::ABS_URI %>
  <%= image_tag content.content_image.pinboard_thumb %>
<% elsif content.content_image? == false && content.content_value =~ URI::ABS_URI %>
  <%= image_tag content.content_value %>
<% else %>
  <%= auto_link content.content_value %>
<% end %>
```

I`m thinking where should I move this logic from if else block. How to do that Rails Way. Move that to helper??

Or is better way? Code below isn`t working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a helper is the right place as the code seems to be about rendering only. So there is no business logic there. If you see yourself putting a lot of stuff like this into helpers, you could have a look at http://github.com/jcasimir/draper which is a gem that implements the presenter pattern.